# Unity5.2.2+Parse1.6.2+iOS9, SignupAsync causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on iPhone

Tags: ios, parse-platform, unity-game-engine, exc-bad-access

On this situation, simply "SignupAsync" causes EXC_BAD_ACCESS on real device only.
On UnityEditor, SignupAsync can be finished without error.
On any case, Users can be created on Parse Server.
How can I avoid this?

[image]

It seems "connection.data" has no "bytes" in this case.(Existing no "bytes" variable causes exc_bad_access i think.)

[image]

Is it Parse SDK bug? Or not?
I have scheduled a release of my newest game in this week, so this problem annoy me... I need anyone help.

Comment: I tried below.

* Create New Project.
* Add Parse from Assetstore.
* Set "ParseInitializeBehaviour" and write simple SignupAsync. This project contains them only.
* Build iOS target.
* Run on iPhone6s.
* Same error (EXC_BAD_ACCESS) Occured.

It may be Unity Parse SDK's bug. Can someone succeed it?

Comment: Sorry this problem has been fixed. Setting "-fno-objc-arc" to WWWConnection.mm caused this.